# Model Formula with deflator

Tags: r, regression

I'm having difficulties to find the right model formula for my model:

$Y_i=a+bX_i$  where Y and X are both deflated by another variable

```
y1/def ~ x1/def + x2/def
```

returns a model with interactions. How can i prevent R from doing so?

Comment: Did this help you get the desired behavior?

Comment: As a word of caution, be careful with dividing by `def`, however--if it's a **random variable** then dividing both sides by `def` could completely change the **functional form** of your regression. Just throwing that out there...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the hints on deflating. I wasnt able to check yet. Will comment when I did so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform a transformation on the variables in the regression, you'll have to use the `I()` function:

```
I(y1/def) ~ I(x1/def) + I(x2/def)
```

Try that instead and see if it works the way you want it to...

#### Explanation:

Basically, you use the `I()` function in a formula whenever you want an expression to be treated "as is". For example, if you have a data frame with three columns, **a**, **b**, & **c**, and you want to regress **c** onto the sum of columns **a** and **b** you would write: `c ~ I(a + b)` since--as you've seen yourself--entering: `c ~ a + b` would give you a totally different regression.